# Can we use 'hysteric' as a verb?

Tags: word-usage, parts-of-speech

This is one instance of the use of 'hysteric' as verb (I think):

> **Natalya Stepanovna:** He's dead. [Pulls Lomov's sleeve] Ivan Vassilevitch! Ivan Vassilevitch! What have you done to me? He's dead. [Falls into an armchair] A doctor, a doctor! [Hysterics]  <sub>"The Proposal" or "The Marruage Proposal"
>    by Anton Chekhov</sub>

However, Merriam-Webster's dictionary, or any standard dictionary on the internet does not mention 'hysteric' as a verb. So, can we use 'hysteric' as a verb? Has it been used in the past?

Comment: Not  sure it is a verb here: ***hysterics*** - https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/hysterics

Comment: [hystericize](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22hystericize%22) is a verb, but it is very rarely used (only 1700 hits on Google).

Comment: No, not a verb, hysterics is being in a state of hysteria.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for analysis of literature / plays. Stage directions are given in headlinese (or worse) and grammar hardly applies.

Comment: @JJJ More like [~140 hits](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EWnoK.png). Google search counts [are not accurate](https://support.google.com/gsa/answer/2672285?hl=en).

Comment: I would use "hysteriatify".  (But for some reason *The New Yorker* always rejects my submissions.)

Answer (score 4):

Even though the other bracketed phrases are verb phrases, "hysterics" isn't being used as a verb here, it's a noun. "Hysterics" here implies "hysterical behavior" of some sort: shrieking, waving hands, acting flustered. A typical expression is "He flew into hysterics when he found out that ...".

I see that [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hysterics) confines its meaning to extreme laughter, crying, or emotion, but I believe various *signs* of emotion such as I mentioned above are included.

Answer (score -1):

You can only use hystericize as a verb, but it's done rarely.

Comment: Please provide corroboration for your answer.